# Is the select() socket function supported for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c++, sockets, windows-phone-8

I'm porting a C++ project to Windows Phone 8.1.  The code makes use of the select() function.  Compiling it under Visual Studio 12 2013 ARM produces compilation errors for all references to the functions, FD_SET(), fd_set, etc.

[The MSDN documentation for select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) infers that it *is* supported by Windows Phone 8 and above, but states that one needs to #include winsock2.h.  It is my understanding that Windows Phone 8 does not support WinSock.

Therefore, is the select() function supported for Windows Phone 8.1?  What needs to be done for the compiler to recognize select, etc. as defined symbols?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, it is supported as seen by the inclusion in the Windows Phone 8.1 API set here:

   [Supported Win32 APIs for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662956.aspx)

   ```
   List of supported Win32 APIs on Windows Phone 8

   Member  Header      DLL Name    Library
   ...
   select  winsock2.h  WS2_32.dll  ws2_32.lib
   ...
   ```
2. `winsock2.h` is indeed supported by Windows Phone 8 and above.  Just use this line in your code:

   ```
   #include <winsock2.h>
   ```

It works just fine:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: A big thank you for checking it out -- I was so sure it would fail.  Very good news!  I will check it in my project, if it works I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: FYI, WinSock is also now supported in Windows Store apps.